# Django Test set attribute and access it in different methods

Tags: python, django

I have a django test that looks like this:

```
class APITests(APITestCase):
    # APITestCase is a django rest framework wrapper for a regular django test
    def setUp(self):
        self.token = ""
        self.fixtures = ['tests/testdata.json']

    def test_client_register(self):
        ....
        self.token = response.json()["token"]
        # at this point, self.token is not ""

    def test_auth_token_verify(self):
        body = {
            "token": self.token  # <-- At this point, self.token is "", why??
        }
        response = self.client.post(reverse("misuper:api_token_verify"), body, format="json")
```

How can I solve this? I need to set an attribute on the test class ("token") that should be populated one test and could be used in the subsequent tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions in a test are not executed in the order they show up.  In reality, `setUp()` is executed, then one test case is executed, then the class is destroyed.  Do not expect to save state between tests.

Tests should be independent units.  A test should not depend on other tests before it to execute.  I can list 2 reasons off the bat: a) tests get harder to maintain with more dependencies b) it becomes very hard to run tests in parallel.

If there is something that must happen in each test, I'd split it out into a separate non-test method, and call it from each test.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.token = ""
    self.fixtures = ['tests/testdata.json']

def updateToken(self, response):
    self.token = response.json()["token"]

def test_client_register(self):
    ....
    updateToken(self, response)

def test_auth_token_verify(self):
    updateToken(self, response)
    body = {
        "token": self.token  # <-- At this point, self.token is "", why??
    }
    response = self.client.post(reverse("misuper:api_token_verify"), body, format="json")
```